# Some media providers blocking UI when calling MediaStore

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, onedrive

I'm calling `MadiaStore` like this (after requesting permissions):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("application/zip");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_RESTORE_REQUEST);
```

I then navigate to Google Drive and select the file and the `Uri` gets returned in `onActivityResult`.

I then try to get a `Cursor` by querying the content resolver, as shown below:

```java
// I'm doing this to get the file size etc
Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(mUri, null, null, null, null);
```

The problem is that the file is not available yet (Google Drive is in the process of downloading it). The UI gets blocked, displaying a black screen, until the file is available and then the above gets triggered/called.

I have tried calling the above in an `AsyncTask` - It works for the blocking of the UI, but only calls the above after the has downloaded.

---

Some providers, like Dropbox, first download the content before returning the `Uri`.

---

**My Question:**

Is there a way that we can prevent this from happening (for example, getting the progress of the file being downloaded, at least)?
If not, what do you suggest?

**Please note** - I only used Google Drive as an example, OneDrive has the same issue.

**Also** - You can reproduce this by clearing the Google Drive application data, then calling the above. It is clearly noticeable when selecting a file size 5MB >

Comment: "Is there a way that we can prevent this from happening" -- what specifically do you mean? If you mean "can we restrict `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to content that already exists locally", you can try adding `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` to your `Intent` and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried adding `CATEGORY_OPENABLE`, the file is still displayed and when selecting it I get the same issue.

Comment: If you switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (at least on Android 4.4+ devices), do you have better luck? You would then switch from your `query()` to using `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare The problem with `DocumentFile` is that the selected file is a zip file and I need to unzip it. I will then have to call `documentFile.getUri()` which in turn has to wait for the file to be downloaded first. I tried this and it has exactly the same behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare I assume there is no way of getting the progress of the file being downloaded by the media provider? Can you please provide any suggestions?

Comment: "I assume there is no way of getting the progress of the file being downloaded by the media provider?" -- AFAIK, correct, though I can't rule out there being something somewhere in the Storage Access Framework that I'm forgetting. "Can you please provide any suggestions?" -- ummm... other than an indefinite `ProgressBar` and a background thread, not really.